# Get a value of for in a label using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

HTML:

```
<label name="table_id" for="1280461">Rock</label>
<label name="table_id" for="1291065">Paper</label>
```

This doesn't work:

```
$$('label[name="table_id"]').each(function(s){ 
  console.log(s.for); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.readAttribute('for');
```

See: http://prototypejs.org/api/element/readattribute

Answer (score 1):

`for` is keyword in Javascript. You can't use it in "`s.for`" form.

Use `DOM Element`'s [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) function:

```
$$('label[name="table_id"]').each(function(s){ 
    console.log(s.getAttribute('for')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle to answer this. Hope this make sense to you.

http://jsfiddle.net/QmEWD/